# error converting jQuery.ajax to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am struggling to convert the following $.ajax using XMLHttpRequest object:

```
function doPost(url, queryString, successCallback) {
   $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : url,
      dataType : 'json',
      data : queryString,
      success : successCallback,
      error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert('ajax:error-' + errorThrown);
      },
      timeout : function() {
         alert('ajax:timeout');
      },
      abort : function() {
         showWaitCursor(false);
         alert('ajax:abort');
         appendLog('doPost:abort');
      },
      parsererror : function() {
         alert('ajax:parsererror');
      }
   });
}
```

What is wrong with the following:

```
function doPost2(url, queryString, successCallback) {
   var kvs = queryString.split("&");

   var formData = new FormData();
   for(var i = 0; i < kvs.length; i++) {
      var kv= kvs[i].split("=");
      var key = kv[0];
      var value = kv[1];
      formData.append(key, value);
   }

   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.addEventListener('load', successCallback, false);

   request.open("POST", url, true);
   request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
   request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   request.send(formData);
}
```

the callback event.target.responseText is "Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@547b6d1c; line: 1, column: 3]"

What is wrong with the above doPost2?